# Show file list with sorting by links count in Unix

Tags: unix, terminal, ls

How can I show file list with sorting by hard links count in Unix terminal (Mac OS)?

**ls -l** shows this data in second column. By how can I sort by this column?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls -l | sort -n -k 2` should work for you.